# How to automatically reposition my-weather-indicator desktop widgets for external monitor

Tags: scripts, indicator

[My-Weather-Indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/install-weather-indicator-ubuntu-14-10) is probably the best weather widget for Ubuntu desktop.

However, one needs to manually **reposition desktop widgets** (e.g. aligned top right) **every time an external monitor is connected** to a laptop.

How about a startup script that will automatically reposition my-weather-indicator's (e.g. 2 "superclock") desktop widgets for external monitor? Or any other (perhaps better) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is a sample startup script

that can be entered into the `Exec=` line of `~/.config/autostart/my-weather-indicator.desktop` file instead of the command `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    MONITORS="$(xrandr | grep -v "eDP1 " | grep -c " connected ")"
    if [[ "$MONITORS" -eq 0 ]]                              # no external monitor, LCD panel only
    then
        MONINTX="$(xrandr | grep "eDP1 connected " | sed -e 's/^eDP1 connected primary //g' -e 's/x.*$//g')"
        MONINTV="$(expr $MONINTX - 316)"
        MONINT1="$(grep -c "\"wp1-x\": $MONINTV" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf")"
        if  [[ "$MONINT1" -eq 0 ]]                          # widget1 not configured for LCD panel
        then
            sed -i "s/\"wp1\-x\"\: [0-9]*/\"wp1\-x\"\: $MONINTV/" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf"
            echo "REFRESH" > "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int"
        fi
        MONINT2="$(grep -c "\"wp2-x\": $MONINTV" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf")"
        if  [[ "$MONINT2" -eq 0 ]]                          # widget2 not configured for LCD panel
        then
            sed -i "s/\"wp2\-x\"\: [0-9]*/\"wp2\-x\"\: $MONINTV/" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf"
            echo "REFRESH" > "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int"
        fi
        if [ -f "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int" ]       # marker file
        then
            if [ -s "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int" ]   # content
            then
                PID="$(ps -e -o pid,cmd | grep "/usr/bin/python3 /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" | egrep -v grep | awk '{print$1}')"
                if [[ "$PID" -eq 0 ]]                       # not running, start
                then
                    rm "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int"
                    "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" &
                else
                    kill -9 "$PID"                          # running, re-start
                    rm "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-int"
                    "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" &
                fi
            fi
        fi
    else                                                    # external monitor connected
        MONEXTX="$(xrandr | grep " connected " | grep -v "eDP1" | sed -e 's/^e*[A-Z]*[A-Z][A-Z][0-9] connected primary //g' -e 's/x.*$//g')"
        MONEXTV="$(expr $MONEXTX - 316)"
        MONEXT1="$(grep -c "\"wp1-x\": $MONEXTV" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf")"
        if  [[ "$MONEXT1" -eq 0 ]]                          # widget1 not configured for external monitor
        then
            sed -i "s/\"wp1\-x\"\: [0-9]*/\"wp1\-x\"\: $MONEXTV/" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf"
            echo "REFRESH" > "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext"
        fi
        MONEXT2="$(grep -c "\"wp2-x\": $MONEXTV" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf")"
        if  [[ "$MONEXT2" -eq 0 ]]                          # widget2 not configured for external monitor
        then
            sed -i "s/\"wp2\-x\"\: [0-9]*/\"wp2\-x\"\: $MONEXTV/" "/home/$USER/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf"
            echo "REFRESH" > "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext"
        fi
        if [ -f "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext" ]       # marker file
        then
            if [ -s "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext" ]   # content
            then
                PID="$(ps -e -o pid,cmd | grep "/usr/bin/python3 /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" | egrep -v grep | awk '{print$1}')"
                if [[ "$PID" -eq 0 ]]                       # not running, start
                then
                    rm "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext"
                    "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" &
                else
                    kill -9 "$PID"                          # running, re-start
                    rm "/tmp/my-weather-indicator_mon-ext"
                    "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" &
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
    PID="$(ps -e -o pid,cmd | grep "/usr/bin/python3 /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" | egrep -v grep | awk '{print$1}')"
    if [[ "$PID" -eq 0 ]]                                   # not running, start
    then
        "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator" &
    fi
    sleep 12
done
```

**CAUTION:** This script has only been tested on a DELL Latitude laptop with **2 desktop widgets using the *superclock* theme**, and might require some further fine-tuning, and it might be a good idea to check if the variables used here will also work in other systems by checking the terminal output of the command `xrandr`

[image]